# Preventing raised div from moving based on screen width

Tags: html, css

I want to keep a div from moving up on mobile devices with smaller widths. I realize I could do it with media queries but I feel there is likely a cleaner way.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 23%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
#titlebackground {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
#title {
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
#titlelocation {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="titlelocation">
      <div id="titlebackground">
        <span id="title">My Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

How do I raise the title so that it is higher than the center of the div, but prevent it from moving up even higher on lower resolutions?

Edit: to reproduce: run code snipped on full screen and then change screen width.. The div moves up the smaller the screen goes.

Comment: Do you want to center *My title* in small devices and desktop?

Comment: I want it raised to about 65% from the bottom of the smaller div, but stay there regardless of device.

Comment: Then, why don't you use 'absolute' position? Your issue dissapears if you use a fixed unit in the padding-top of the wrapper, but then you loose the proportion you want...

Comment: There is more complexity to the div's that is being shown. It is being populated by a jQuery plugin and absolute doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.wrapper` has a percentage padding `padding-top: 23%`, so at mobile that is gonna be alot less than at desktop you can put a fixed `px` padding so it's the same across all devices.

```
.wrapper{
    background: no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) instead of percentage and then give your desire value to it. `vh`is measured regarding to the height of device.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 65vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
#titlebackground {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
#title {
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
#titlelocation {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="titlelocation">
      <div id="titlebackground">
        <span id="title">My Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning. It's exactly what you're looking for:

```css
.wrapper{
 background: no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
#titlebackground {
     background: rgba(0 , 0 , 0 , .5);
}
#title {
      font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 5em;
      font-weight: 900;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
}
#titlelocation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 65%;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="titlelocation">
          <div id="titlebackground">
            <span id="title">My Title</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

**EDIT:** Using vh as units for the padding is also possible, but won't work in all browsers, specially the old ones.